# Предварительный просмотр фото и размера картинки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать предварительный просмотр фото и размера картинки в браузере перед загрузкой на сервер ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот нашел один хороший скрипт, может тебе подойдет, просто удали если нужны , такие функции как имя файла и ширина и высота картинки.

```js
function formatSize(length) {
  var i = 0,
    type = ['б', 'Кб', 'Мб', 'Гб', 'Тб', 'Пб'];
  while ((length / 1000 | 0) && i < type.length - 1) {
    length /= 1024;
    i++;
  }
  return length.toFixed(2) + ' ' + type[i];
}


(function() {
  $("#controls button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return $("#file").click();
  });

  $("#file").change(function(e) {
    var file, reader;
    file = e.target.files[0];
    $("#image_name").text(file.name);
    $("#image_type").text(file.type);
    $("#image_size").text("" + formatSize(file.size));
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var image;
      image = new Image();
      image.src = e.target.result;
      return image.onload = function() {
        $("#image_dimensions").text("" + this.width + " x " + this.height);
        return $("#preview img").attr('src', this.src);
      };
    };
    return reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
body {
  background: #555555;
}
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-left: 1px solid #555555;
  border-right: 1px solid #555555;
}
button {
  -moz-transition-property: background;
  -o-transition-property: background;
  -webkit-transition-property: background;
  transition-property: background;
  -moz-transition-duration: 133ms;
  -o-transition-duration: 133ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 133ms;
  transition-duration: 133ms;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #1166dd;
  color: white;
}
button:hover {
  background: #3281ef;
}
#file {
  display: none;
}
#results {
  margin: 10px 0;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#results dt {
  width: 8em;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#preview img {
  height: 300px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 2px dashed #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <h1>Image Preview</h1>
  <input accept='image/*' id='file' type='file'>
  <div id='controls'>
    <button href='#'>Select Image</button>
  </div>
  <div id='results'>
    <dl>
      <dt>Name</dt>
      <dd id='image_name'>-</dd>
      <dt>Type</dt>
      <dd id='image_type'>-</dd>
      <dt>Size</dt>
      <dd id='image_size'>-</dd>
      <dt>Dimensions</dt>
      <dd id='image_dimensions'>-</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
  <div id='preview'>
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```